# Intersection of an open dense set and any dense set is dense.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am going through an introductory topology chapter and finding some difficulty in the following question. I had a chance to go through Daniel's and Brian's answers on this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603520/intersection-of-dense-sets).
However, I am still a bit not convinced.

> If $D_1$ is an open dense set in  $\mathbb R^p$ and $D_2$ is any dense set in $\mathbb R^p$, then,Show that $D_1 \cap D_2$ are also dense in $\mathbb R^p$ .

**Attempt:** Given that $D_1$ is an open dense set in  $\mathbb R^p$ which means if $x \in D_1^c$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one element of $D_1$.

But, this fact is contradictory because elements of $D_1$ are not supposed to be in **every** neighborhood of elements in $D_1^c$.

> $(a)~$Hence, can we infer that $D_1^c$ must not have any non void open set else any open ball in $D_1^c$ will also contain elements of $D_1$ which is a contradiction?

Suppose that $D_1 \cap D_2$ is not dense in $\mathbb R^p$. Then, for some $y \in \mathbb R^p$, there is a neighborhood of $y = B(y,r)$ which does not contain any element of $D_1 \cap D_2$.

This is certainly possible because $B(y,r)$ can contain elements of $D_1/ (D_1 \cap D_2)$ and $D_2/ (D_1 \cap D_2)$.

How do I move forward?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $D_{1} \cap D_{2}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$, you can show it intersects every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$.  That is one characterization of density.

So, let $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be an arbitrary open set.  Since $D_{1}$ is dense, $D_{1} \cap O \neq \emptyset$.  Furthermore, $D_{1} \cap O$ is open, since both sets are open.  So we know by the nonempty intersection $\exists x \in D_{1} \cap O$.  Since the intersection is open, $\exists \epsilon_{x} > 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_{x}) \subseteq D_{1} \cap O$.

But $B(x, \epsilon_{x})$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$, and thus since $D_{2}$ is dense, $D_{2} \cap B(x, \epsilon_{x}) \neq \emptyset$.  But since this ball is contained in $O \cap D_{1}$, this implies $D_{2}$ intersects $O \cap D_{1}$.  Written down, this says $D_{2} \cap (D_{1} \cap O) \neq \emptyset$.

Since set intersection is associative, this means $(D_{1} \cap D_{2}) \cap O \neq \emptyset$ for any arbitrary open set $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p}$, which implies $D_{1}\cap D_{2}$ is dense by our characterization of density.

Comment: Given that $D_1$ is an open dense set in  $\mathbb R^p$ which means if $x \in D_1^c$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one element of $D_1$.

But, this fact is contradictory because elements of $D_1$ are not supposed to be in **every** neighborhood of elements in $D_1^c \\$.

Hence, can we infer that $D_1^c$ must not have any non void open set else any open ball in $D_1^c$ will also contain elements of $D_1$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: @VHP Since $D_{1}$ is open and dense, that means $D_{1}^{c}$ is **nowhere dense** (i.e., its closure has empty interior).  To prove this, first note that $\overline{D_{1}^{c}} = D_{1}^{c}$ since $D_{1}^{c}$ is closed.  Now, suppose that $\exists x \in (D_{1}^{c})^{o}$ (the interior of $D_{1}^{c}$).  Since this interior is open, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq (D_{1}^{c})^{o}$.  But since $B(x, \epsilon)$ is open, it intersects $D_{1}$, and so it cannot be contained in $(D_{1}^{c})^{o}$, which implies $(D_{1}^{c})^{o}$ is empty, and thus $D_{1}^{c}$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: @VHP Is that what you were trying to say?  If so, can you explain what the contradiction was you were trying to find?  Were you assuming $D_{1} \cap D_{2}$ is *not* dense in the beginning in order to arrive at the contradiction you think you found?

Comment: Uhm .. no actually.. I was trying to find out if $D_1^c$ can have any non void open set?

Comment: I  think it can't because $D_1$ is dense, hence, if $x \in D_1^c$, then every nbd of $x$ contains an element of $D_1$. Is this possible for an element in $D_1^c?$

Comment: @VHP Yes, you are trying figure out whether or not $D_{1}^{c}$ is nowhere dense.  If it is nowhere dense, then it has no non-void open set.  If it is *not* nowhere dense, it has a non-void open set.  But we know now that it is nowhere dense based on my proof above.  And you are completely correct that the proof relies on the fact tht $D_{1}$ is dense.  You are right.  $D_{1}^{c}$ contains no non-void set (i.e., $D_{1}^{c}$ is nowhere dense), precisely because $D_{1}$ is dense.

Comment: @VHP Now that you have established $D_{1}^{c}$ is nowhere dense, are you trying to use this fact to give an alternate proof to the one I posted of $D_{1} \cap D_{2}$ being dense?

Comment: yeah, I was trying to move forward from there ..

Comment: @VHP I'm not sure how to use the fact that $D_{1}^{c}$ is nowhere dense to prove $D_{1} \cap D_{2}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$, but in any case, we don't need to do that, because we have a pretty straightforward proof already.  However, it's nice that you unlocked the feature that $D_{1}^{c}$ is nowhere dense.  I didn't realize this immediately when proving the original statement.  And it might be useful in an alternative proof to the statement.  I'm just not sure.

Comment: Np :-) .. Thank you for the answer :-)

Comment: @VHP By the way, I just wanted to make one clarification.  In general, a set is *nowhere dense* if its **closure** has empty interior.  In other words, if its *closure* has no non-void open sets.  The reason we didn't talk about the closure of $D_{1}^{c}$ when saying it is nowhere dense is that the closure of $D_{1}^{c}$ is itself, because it is a closed set.  But in general, to prove $A$ is nowhere dense, you have to show that the closure of $A$, $\overline{A}$, has no non-void open sets.  If $A$ is already closed, then we can just show $A$ has no non-void open sets for $A$ to be nowhr dnse.

Comment: Oh okay .. I get that