# If $A, B$ are open dense subsets of a metric space $X$, is their intersection dense??

Tags: metric-spaces

If $A, B$ are open dense subsets of a metric space $X$, is their intersection dense??
We know normally intersection of two dense sets are not dense.

Comment: Oops, did not see open. Yes.

Comment: Note that it’s enough to know that one of the open sets is dense: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603520/intersection-of-dense-sets) and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be any arbitrary open set. Then note that $U \bigcap (A \bigcap B) = (U \bigcap A )\bigcap B$. Here $U$ and $A$ are open sets so $(U \bigcap A )$ is open and $B$ being dense.....

Comment: Can you please clarify how that is enough? Given $x \in X$, we need to show that $x$ belongs to closure of $A \bigcap B$...