# Is $C_c^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove that $C_c^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)=C_c(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I know that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

$C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is trivially dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Using that result [Intersection of Dense Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603520/intersection-of-dense-sets?rq=1), I see that  it is sufficient that one of the dense sets is open. How can I prove it?

Comment: What norm on the intersection are you using? sum of norms?

Comment: Can't I use the $\| \cdot \|_p$ norm on the intersection?

Comment: This should follow from the density of $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, no? Also the statement "$C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is trivially dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$" is incorrect.

Comment: You can, but then its not a Banach space, as its completion is of course $L^p$. The sum of norms makes the intersection of Banach spaces into another Banach space

Comment: @cameron-williams why?

Comment: Are polynomials in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams no, $f(x)=x^2$ for example is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ because $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\lvert x^{2}\rvert \right)^{2} \, dx = \infty$

Comment: Correct. And polynomials are in $C^k$, so you can see that your statement is false.

Comment: Take $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $f_n=(1-\dfrac{1}{n}) f$ is in $ C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$  and $f_n \rightarrow f$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. 
Now $\lvert f_n - f \lvert^p= \lvert f_n\lvert ^p \leq \lvert f \lvert ^p \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now I can use Dominated Convergence Theorem and then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \| f_n-f \|_p^p=0$.

Comment: No, neither of those sets is open.

Comment: @CalvinKhor What norm on $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are you referring to? These functions are not bounded, need not be integrable..

Comment: I assumed the notation of eg Evans so sum of sup norms of derivatives which makes the set different from the vector space of all $C^k$ functions but you’re right maybe OP did not mean it @AndrewMcMillan